# How do I draw a line connecting 2 imageButtons in android?

Tags: android

I am trying to create a line connecting 2 ImageButtons on screen, such that the line will start at button one, and end at button two. I have the buttons placed on the screen in an xml file and I am trying to code a way to draw a set of lines that will correctly scale when I use a different screen size. Do I have to put the line in manually for each different screen size?

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (container == null) {

    }
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        size = 0;
        View v = (RelativeLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.minor_fragment_two, container,     false);
        final ImageButton one = (ImageButton)v.findViewById(R.id.one);
        final ImageButton two = (ImageButton)v.findViewById(R.id.two);
        final ImageButton three = (ImageButton)v.findViewById(R.id.three);
        final ImageButton four = (ImageButton)v.findViewById(R.id.four);
        final ImageButton five = (ImageButton)v.findViewById(R.id.five);
        final ImageButton six = (ImageButton)v.findViewById(R.id.six);
        final ImageButton seven = (ImageButton)v.findViewById(R.id.seven);
        final ImageButton eight = (ImageButton)v.findViewById(R.id.eight);
    imageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imView);
        //Display currentDisplay = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        Display currentDisplay = ((WindowManager) v.getContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();

        float dw = currentDisplay.getWidth();
        float dh = currentDisplay.getHeight();

        bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap((int) dw, (int) dh,
                Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(10);
        onex = one.getX();
        oney = one.getY();
        twox = two.getX();
        twoy = two.getY();
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                "Position :" + onex + " " + oney + " " + twox + " " + twoy, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
        canvas.drawLine(onex,oney,twox,twoy,paint);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        //return (LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.minor_fragment_two, container, false);
        return v;
    }    


    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/reduced"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/imView"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="41dp"
        android:layout_height="41dp"
        android:id="@+id/one"
        android:background="@drawable/first_alpha"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="170dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="41dp"
        android:layout_height="41dp"
        android:id="@+id/two"
        android:background="@drawable/first_alpha"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="120dp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="41dp"
        android:layout_height="41dp"
        android:id="@+id/three"
        android:background="@drawable/first_alpha"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="210dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="85dp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="41dp"
        android:layout_height="41dp"
        android:id="@+id/four"
        android:background="@drawable/first_alpha"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="330dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="120dp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:id="@+id/five"
        android:background="@drawable/first_alpha"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginTop="360dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="145dp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="41dp"
        android:layout_height="41dp"
        android:id="@+id/six"
        android:background="@drawable/first_alpha"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="380dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="41dp"
        android:layout_height="41dp"
        android:id="@+id/seven"
        android:background="@drawable/first_alpha"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="410dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="190dp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="41dp"
        android:layout_height="41dp"
        android:id="@+id/eight"
        android:background="@drawable/first_alpha"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="460dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="135dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can you post image how you are expecting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't say how the image is off or post a screenshot of what it looks like. But the problem may be you are getting the display width and height, but that isn't the same as the drawable area of your activity (action bar, system area at top and bottom are included).

Instead of getting the width and height of display, wait for the layout complete event to do your drawing there and create a bitmap matching the size of the imView

```
ViewTreeObserver vt = view.getViewTreeObserver();
vt.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        float dw = imView.getWidth();
        float dh = imView.getHeight();

        // Do your drawing here...
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As much as I understood your question, you can try like this :

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnOne"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#000000"
            android:text="One"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/v1"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/btnOne"
            android:background="#000000" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnTwo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/v1"
            android:background="#000000"
            android:text="Two"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Please let me know if I have got you wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I think this code you can use, it is for all device.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_gravity="center">


<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:text="button1" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="button2" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/btn2"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/btn1"
    android:background="@color/blue" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]